# unable to boot from usb

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios

I am trying to install Windows 7 on my desktop PC:

I have the OS on a bootable USB and used `Diskpart` to make the USB drive bootable. I restarted my system, went into the BIOS settings and changed the boot priority to the USB drive, saved the changes, and exited.  Instead of the USB booting, all I get is a blank screen right after I exit from the BIOS settings.

It does not even go to the screen where I can get into the BIOS settings again, remaining a blank and black screen.  I've tried removing the battery to reset the BIOS to default and also configured the jumper on the board, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: You are trying to install Windows 7 on your desktop? You should use the tool Rufus https://rufus.ie/ or other to burn the image of a .iso onto your Pen Drive. It will make it bootable.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using third party softwares like Rufus : https://rufus.ie

Comment: I normally do it through CMD and it works in other laptops and desktops. That's why i don't use any third party software's. Nevertheless, i will surely give it a go now.

Comment: @vssher. what about the values that are selected by default in rufus.?? i am confused about partition scheme and target system. Its default value is set to GPT and UEFI(non CSM) by default. Does these values require any changes??

Comment: As far as Windows 7 I have used _Add fixes for old BIOS_ Everything else should work well enough to install it.

Comment: @kulbans1991 you can take hints : https://kb.iu.edu/d/bciz and https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.maketecheasier.com/use-rufus-create-bootable-flash-drive/%3famp

Comment: You need a functional ISO of Windows 7 to make a Win7 USB bootable. What is the source of the OS on your flash drive? Rufus automatically makes the right settings for an ISO.

Comment: @vssher i tried rufus. it is the same story yet again. changed hard disk priority and saved the changes. yet again booting is not happening. its in the black screen